# estimating cutoff frequency from magnitude of phasor transfer function

Tags: circuit-analysis

Given the **magnitude** of a transfer function for an RC high pass filter:

$$|H(\omega)| = \frac{\omega RC}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2 R^2 C^2}}\tag{1}$$

The textbook say:, "we take a digression to learn how to estimate the cutoff frequency.  This occurs when |H| is at half of its peak value, that is:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2 R^2 C^2}}\tag{2}$$

**I'm not sure I understand this statement..  how is:**

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

**half of the value of:**

$$|H(\omega)|$$

---

anyways, if you solve the equation (2) you get a cutoff frequency of:

$$2 = 1 + \omega_c^2 R^2 C^2$$

$$\omega_c = \frac{1}{RC}$$

textbook continues: "so by tuning the values of resistor and capacitor, we can contrutruct a high pass filter with the desired cutoff frequency..."

---

I could brute force it and get the cutoff frequency by plotting the magnitude function with matplotlib...but i though it would be useful to know how to estimate it from the magnitude of the transfer function...

Comment: The cutoff frequency is defined at half-power.

Comment: I don't know if this helps:   $$H(\omega) = \frac{\omega R C}{\sqrt{1+(\omega R C)}^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\omega R C}\sqrt{1+ (\omega R C)^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{(\omega RC)^2 } + 1}}$$

Comment: It's half-power, pico. Not half-voltage. The transfer function is the Vout/Vin ratio, not the power ratio. Just FYI. Another way to look at it is that it will occur right at the inflection point of phase.

Comment: that's way its **magnitude** of the transfer function. $$|H(\omega)| = \sqrt{ (H_I)^2 + (H_R)^2}$$.   its a square of the real and imaginary components....

Comment: forgot to put  $$|H(\omega)|$$ for first comment..

Comment: Does the \$\sqrt{2}\$ factor makes sense, yet? Do you remember that \$P\propto V^2\$?

Comment: I know that "root mean square" average of a sinusoidal signal is found by dividing the sinusoidal by $$\sqrt{2}$$...  that would be the average magnitude over one period... in the case of a sin, the would be like taking the positive crests of the wave and drawing a line through it that is at a level with half of the area is above and half below the line...

Comment: but if you equate $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ with $$|H(\omega)|$$ doesn't that imply the max amplitude of $$|H(\omega)|$$ is one?  I don;t really follow there logic there...

Comment: the other part that's wierd is the $$\omega RC$$ term that disappears from the numerator...

Comment: i think taking $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ the magnitude of transfer function doesn't make sense.... because its a knee graph in frequency domain,not a sin graph in time domain... maybe its just a mistake in the book...

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow your jumping this way and that. But I want you to think more slowly and calmly. The cutoff frequency is about power. It's not about voltage. It is where the half-power point occurs. Not where the half-voltage point occurs. And also keep in mind that we are thinking in the frequency domain. Not the time domain. So, the frequency is a continuous sine (or cosine, I don't care.)

Comment: Suppose the sine is \$A_0\operatorname{sin}\left(\omega t\right)\$. The load is \$R\$. So the power is what? Perhaps \$P=f\cdot\int_{_0}^{^\frac1{f}}\frac{A_0^2\operatorname{sin}^2\left(\omega t\right)}{R}\:\text{d}t\$? If we substitute \$\theta=\omega\,t\$, then \$\text{d}\theta=2\pi\,f\,\text{d}t\$ and so \$P=\frac1{2\pi}\cdot\int_{_0}^{2\pi}\frac{A_0^2\operatorname{sin}^2\left(\theta\right)}{R}\:\text{d}\theta=\frac12\frac{A_0^2}{R}\$. I think you can see that \$P\propto A^2_0\$.

Comment: And also that if you want to cut the power in half, then you need to divide \$A_0\$ by the \$\sqrt{2}\$. So if \$V_\text{OUT}\$ is reduced by the \$\sqrt{2}\$ then the power is reduced by half. So you want to see that \$\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}\$ droops from \$1\$ down to \$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\$, yes? That is, if you are looking for the half-power point. (Which you are.)